# Spacing between grid cells in Zurb Foundation 4

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, css-frameworks

Is there an easy way to have spacing between the grid cells in Zurb Foundation 4? I don't want to mess with the CSS of the Foundation elements as that may throw something else off. There's a `$column-gutter` SCSS variable in their [Grid docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html):

```
$column-gutter: 1.875em !default;
```

However, I'm not sure what that's for as I have seemingly zero space between columns, not 1.875em. Am I expected to just make sure all content within the cells have padding around them?

Comment: Do you mean like padding? It would be helpful with an example.

Comment: yes padding. If I have content inside the grid cells, the content is flush against the sides

Comment: I'd like to know what the point of `$column-gutter` is, as I can't see it having any effect either. We must be missing a trick here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use a separate stylesheet that is loaded **after** the foundation.css where the content looks something like this:

```
@media only screen {
  .row .columns, .row .column {
    padding-left: 10px; /* change the values to anything that you want */
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

I put it in the @media only screen since for printing you might not want to have it display with the extra padding.

**[Example of this here](http://jsfiddle.net/emilhem/pXVR3/3/)**

If you want to use this extra padding while printing you have to use the following:

```
.row .columns, .row .column {
  padding-left: 10px !important; /* change the values to anything that you want */
  padding-right: 10px !important;
}
```

You **have** to use the important part since there's a @media only screen in the default foundation.css that will override your values.

### EDIT

Just use another separate class for the columns that you want the extra padding applied to.
Example:

```
.extra-padding {
  padding-left: 10px !important; /* change the values to anything that you want */
  padding-right: 10px !important;
}
```

**[Example of this here](http://jsfiddle.net/emilhem/WuF3D/)**

Comment: Makes sense, my only concern if this is going to affect other parts of foundation in some way?

Comment: It will not affect Foundation itself but it might change some other layouts that you don't want to change. Check out my edited post.

Answer (score 2):

You can add offsets

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-1 columns">1</div>
  <div class="large-10 large-offset-1 columns">10, offset 1</div>
</div>
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

Comment: The question was for modifying the existing gutter to a diff value, not introducing extra cols.